# Indirect function to get column name of cell intersect in Excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel, based on my data, i am placing an "x" into the specific row, i am looking for a formula to return the column header name ( in my case its actually not in row1, and i am using Excel tables).

[image]

The Formula i currently have is:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("x",B2:F2,0)+1,4))
```

As you can see. I am having to add 1 to my match position, since the match is finding the relative position of the match ( my data has any numver of columns before the table.

What would be the best formula to reach the same outcome of my current formula?

Comment: `=INDEX($B$1:$F$1,MATCH("x",B2:F2,0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `XLOOKUP()` does the job.

```
=XLOOKUP("x",B2:F2,B$1:F$1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your version of excel support `FILTER()` function then I would recommend to use it. Try-

```
=FILTER($B$1:$F$1,B2:F2="x")
```

To make it dynamic spill array use `BYROW()`.

```
=BYROW(B2:F7,LAMBDA(rw,FILTER(B1:F1,rw="x")))
```

[image]